# Insufficient space to save data in my mobile

Tags: internal-storage

Data is not saving or transferring to the memory card, and the phone memory shows no more space available to save data in phone.

Answer (score 2):

It happens to me also. You can solve it very easily.

1. Go to file manager and open DCIM folder.
2. In DCIM folder you can find a hidden file named thumbnails. This should be a very large file. Delete that file.
3. Now check free space in your SD Card. (Thumbnails will be created automatically after deletion. So delete it every day to free space.)